# Why am I getting this error in PowerShell even though the CMDpath I entered is correct?

Tags: powershell, exception, powershell-2.0, filepath, computer-forensics

I was trying these power forensics command from the powerforensics website the 1st two commands worked perfectly while the next 3 commands gave errors, I am sharing one of the errors below. Please tell me the solution to get rid of this error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS5Fv.jpg)What's wrong with the path of the cmd?

Command - `PS C:> Get-ForensicFileRecord -Path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`

> Error: Get-ForensicFileRecord : Path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe not
> found. At line:1 char:1
>
> Get-ForensicFileRecord -Path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe   +
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ForensicFileRecord],
> Exception   + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> System.Exception,PowerForensics.Cmdlets.GetFileRecordCommand

link which I followed for this tutorial: https://powerforensics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modulehelp/Get-ForensicFileRecord

PS: This command worked fine in one of my friend's machine but its throwing error for my machine.

> 

Comment: Make sure you run PowerShell as administrator. You could also try running `Get-ForensicFileRecord -Path $env:ComSpec`.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have the module installed in your system. It doesn't come by default.

So, what you need to do is below:

```
#To Find the module
Find-Module -Name *Forensic*
```

The Module name is actually `PowerForensics`. So, you can install it using:

```
Install-Module -Name PowerForensics
```

Press **A**, to Confirm All installation.
Then,

```
#To Import the module
Import-Module PowerForensics

#To Get all the available commands in the module
Get-Command -Module PowerForensics
```

Comment: A missing cmdlet or function name should generate a different error (`The term 'Get-ForensicFileRecord' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`), don't you think?

Comment: @Ranadip Dutta I have completed all the installation process , after that only I tried these commands as 1st two command worked fine i.e [ADMIN]: PS C:\> $mft = Get-ForensicFileRecord and [ADMIN]: PS C:\> Get-ForensicFileRecord -VolumeName C: -Index 0

Comment: for `cmd.exe`, it normally should throw error. But if you copy the cmd.exe from system32 and put it in some other folder, then give that path, it would work.. It is happening because of permission issue. PS is not able to pick the path.